# Classifying curves and surfaces - Linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality, curves

I have been given the following question on a homework sheet:

[image]

I was wondering if I could have some help. I have this so far:

$x^2-y^2+2xy-1 = (x+y)^2-2y^2-1 = 0$

and so $(x+y)^2-2y^2=1$.

I can clearly see that this is a hyperbola. But if I let

$x'=x+y$ and

$y'=y$

so that it is in the correct form, I believe this actually distorts the curve.

How can I make a suitable change of co-ordinates to show that it is a hyperbola without distorting the curve? My thoughts are along the same lines as normalisation and orthogonal bases, but I am just looking for some guidance as to whether I am heading in the correct direction and a way to do so without distorting the curve.

Comment: The curve is rotated. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102328/rotating-a-conic-section-to-eliminate-the-xy-term)