# Stretching an ellipse along major or minor axis

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Consider the ellipse given by:

$$
Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F =0.
$$

What is the equation of an ellipse which has major and minor axis equal to $p$ times the major and minor axis length of the above ellipse.

My attempt is as follows:
We can remove rotation, increase axis length and then rotate back. An example of rotation is given below:

[Rotating a conic section to eliminate the $xy$ term](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102328/rotating-a-conic-section-to-eliminate-the-xy-term).

I am wondering if there is less complicated intuition into this problem or less complicated way.

Comment: May be projective geometry has an elegant solution among parallel sections after locating the original cone apex projection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the standard results [**here**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839510/how-to-get-the-correct-angle-of-the-ellipse-after-approximation/1840050#1840050), the centre is given by

$$(h,k)=
\left(
  \frac{2CD-BE}{B^2-4AC}, \frac{2AE-BD}{B^2-4AC}
\right)$$

and the transformed conics is

$$\frac{A+C \color{red}{\pm} \sqrt{(A-C)^{2}+B^{2}}}{2} X^2+
\frac{A+C \color{red}{\mp} \sqrt{(A-C)^{2}+B^{2}}}{2} Y^2+
\frac
{\det
  \begin{pmatrix}
    A & \frac{B}{2} & \frac{D}{2} \\
    \frac{B}{2} & C & \frac{E}{2} \\
    \frac{D}{2} & \frac{E}{2} & F
  \end{pmatrix}}
{\det
  \begin{pmatrix}
    A & \frac{B}{2} \\
    \frac{B}{2} & C \\
  \end{pmatrix}}=0$$

> It's just simply re-scaling the constant term $F$, that is
>
> $$Ax^2+Bxy+Cy^2+Dx+Ey+\color{blue}{F'}=0$$ where
>
> $$p^2
> \det
> \begin{pmatrix}
>   A & \frac{B}{2} & \frac{D}{2} \\
>   \frac{B}{2} & C & \frac{E}{2} \\
>   \frac{D}{2} & \frac{E}{2} & F
> \end{pmatrix}
> =
> \det
> \begin{pmatrix}
>   A & \frac{B}{2} & \frac{D}{2} \\
>   \frac{B}{2} & C & \frac{E}{2} \\
>   \frac{D}{2} & \frac{E}{2} & \color{blue}{F'}
> \end{pmatrix}$$
>
> On solving,
>
> $$\color{blue}{F'}=
> \frac{1}
>      {\det
>       \begin{pmatrix}
>         A & \frac{B}{2} \\
>         \frac{B}{2} & C \\
>       \end{pmatrix}}
> \left[
>   \frac{AE^2+CD^2-BDE}{4}+p^2
>       \det
>       \begin{pmatrix}
>         A & \frac{B}{2} & \frac{D}{2} \\
>         \frac{B}{2} & C & \frac{E}{2} \\
>         \frac{D}{2} & \frac{E}{2} & F
>       \end{pmatrix}
> \right]
> $$

Comment: What are $a,b,c,d,e$? And I think you mean $p^2$ not $\sqrt{p}$.

Comment: @Jan-MagnusØkland Answer revised.

Answer (score 0):

You obtain this effect by rescaling the coordinate axis by the factor $p$, and the equation becomes

$$
A\frac{x^2}{p^2} + B\frac{xy}{p^2} + C\frac{y^2}{p^2} + D\frac{x}{p} + E\frac{y}{p} + F =0.
$$

If the center must remain unchanged, translate the center to the origin (the center is found by solving $2Ax+By+F=0,Cx+2Dy+E=0$), dilate and translate back.

The combined transform is

$$x\to\frac{x-x_c}p+x_c,\\y\to\frac{y-y_c}p+y_c.$$